# How to translate this ternary operator expression into if/else blocks?

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time to "translate" this expression using JS ternary operators into if/else statement, which help me visualise better what is happening in the code.

```
mouseX = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
```

Comment: you use `if (condition) { mouseX = when true } else { when false }` as opposed to `mouseX = condition ? when true : when false` - note, `when false` will be a second  `if (condtion)  { mouseX = when true } else { mouseX = when false }`

Answer (score 2):

We can try writing:

```
if (window.Event) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
}
else {
    var scroll;
    if (document.documentElement.scrollLeft) {
        scroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    }
    else {
        scroll = document.body.scrollLeft;
    }
    mouseX = event.clientX + scroll;
}
```

I pulled out the nested ternary expression into a variable `scroll`.  This makes it much easier to rewrite the logic.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be clearer if you indent your original code - changing only whitespace, your original code is:

```
mouseX = (window.Event)
  ? e.pageX
  : event.clientX + (
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft
    ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft
    : document.body.scrollLeft
  );
```

Translating that, you get:

```
if (window.Event)
  mouseX = e.pageX;
else {
  let add;
  if (document.documentElement.scrollLeft)
    add = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  else
    add = document.body.scrollLeft;
  mouseX = event.clientX + add;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to suggest you to use some linting (eslint, jslint, tslint etc) tool and prettier. To have better code formatting. It helps in long run.

The other answers are also valid. But I want to write one.

```
if (window.Event) {
  mouseX = e.pageX;
} else {
  let scroll;
  if (document.documentElement.scrollLeft) {
    scroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  } else {
    scroll = document.body.scrollLeft;
  }
  mouseX = event.clientX + scroll;
}
```